# XAMLParseException driving me CRAZY!

Tags: xaml, xamlparseexception

THIS XAMLParseException IS DRIVING ME CRAZY!! I am using .NET 3.5 in Visual Studio 1020 This is my xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WinformsHost.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Advanced Notepad" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">

        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Header="_New" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Open..." />
            <MenuItem Header="_Save" />
            <MenuItem Header="S_ave As..." />
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="Page Setup" />
            <MenuItem Header="Print" />
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="Exit" />
        </MenuItem>

        <MenuItem Header="Edit">
            <MenuItem Header="Undo" />
            <MenuItem Header="Redo" />
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="Cut" />
            <MenuItem Header="Copy" />
            <MenuItem Header="Paste" />
            <MenuItem Header="Delete"  />
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="Time/Date" />
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="Preferences" />
        </MenuItem>

        <MenuItem Header="Format">
            <MenuItem Header="Word Wrap" IsCheckable="True" />
            <MenuItem Header="Font..." />
        </MenuItem>

        <MenuItem Header="View">
            <MenuItem Header="Status Bar" IsCheckable="True" />
        </MenuItem>

        <MenuItem Header="Language">
            <RadioButton x:Name="rbtCmake" Checked="rbtCmake_Checked" Content="Cmake" />
            <RadioButton x:Name="rbtCSharp" Content="C#" />
            <RadioButton x:Name="rbtHTML" Content="HTML" />
            <RadioButton x:Name="rbtPython" Content="Python" />
            <Separator />
            <RadioButton x:Name="rbtText" IsChecked="True" Content="Text" />
        </MenuItem>

        <MenuItem Header="Help">
            <MenuItem Header="View Help" />
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="About Notepad" />
        </MenuItem>

    </Menu>
    <StatusBar x:Name="stbStatus" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtStatus" Text="Status" />
    </StatusBar>
</DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Then again it might be my code? Here is the exception:
`System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException was unhandled
  Message=Cannot create instance of 'MainWindow' defined in assembly 'Notepad, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  Error in markup file 'MainWindow.xaml' Line 1 Position 9.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  LineNumber=1
  LinePosition=9
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException.ThrowException(String message, Exception innerException, Int32 lineNumber, Int32 linePosition, Uri baseUri, XamlObjectIds currentXamlObjectIds, XamlObjectIds contextXamlObjectIds, Type objectType)
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException.ThrowException(ParserContext parserContext, Int32 lineNumber, Int32 linePosition, String message, Exception innerException)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ThrowExceptionWithLine(String message, Exception innerException)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.CreateInstanceFromType(Type type, Int16 typeId, Boolean throwOnFail)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.GetElementAndFlags(BamlElementStartRecord bamlElementStartRecord, Object& element, ReaderFlags& flags, Type& delayCreatedType, Int16& delayCreatedTypeId)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.BaseReadElementStartRecord(BamlElementStartRecord bamlElementRecord)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ReadElementStartRecord(BamlElementStartRecord bamlElementRecord)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ReadRecord(BamlRecord bamlRecord)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.Read(Boolean singleRecord)
       at System.Windows.Markup.TreeBuilderBamlTranslator.ParseFragment()
       at System.Windows.Markup.TreeBuilder.Parse()
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
       at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(Stream stream, ParserContext pc)
       at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Uri resourceLocator, Boolean bSkipJournaledProperties)
       at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
       at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__0(Object unused)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method, Object arg)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
       at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run()
       at WinformsHost.App.Main() in C:\Users\Mohit\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Notepad\Notepad\obj\x86\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
       Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
       Source=mscorlib
       StackTrace:
            at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
            at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache)
            at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache)
            at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
            at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.CreateInstanceFromType(Type type, Int16 typeId, Boolean throwOnFail)
       InnerException: NLog.Config.NLogConfigurationException
            Message=Exception occured when loading configuration from 'C:\Users\Mohit\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Notepad\Notepad\bin\Debug\NLog.config'
            Source=NLog
            StackTrace:
                 at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration..ctor(String fileName, Boolean ignoreErrors)
                 at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration..ctor(String fileName)
                 at NLog.LogFactory.get_Configuration()
                 at NLog.LogFactory.GetLogger(LoggerCacheKey cacheKey)
                 at NLog.LogFactory.GetLogger(String name)
                 at NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()
                 at WinformsHost.MainWindow..ctor() in C:\Users\Mohit\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Notepad\Notepad\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 15
            InnerException: NLog.Config.NLogConfigurationException
                 Message=Target console not found.
                 Source=NLog
                 StackTrace:
                      at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ConfigureRulesFromElement(LoggingConfiguration config, LoggingRuleCollection rules, XmlElement element)
                      at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ConfigureFromXmlElement(XmlElement configElement, String baseDirectory)
                      at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ConfigureFromFile(String fileName)
                      at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration..ctor(String fileName, Boolean ignoreErrors)
                 InnerException:`

Comment: Do you actually have that backtick in your code? (right near the end of the 'Window' tag ...

Comment: No, sorry. Just by bad formating.

Comment: If it's not the backtick, what's the error message and what line is it pointing at?

Comment: Hmm. Have you defined the Window_Load event?

Comment: silky: a missing event handler would normally cause a compiler error rather than a runtime error.

Comment: Yes the event handler is defined

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think this is really a XamlParseException: I think it's a TargetInvocationException which has gotten wrapped in a XamlParseException.  Take a look at the ultimate inner exception:

> NLog.Config.NLogConfigurationException
>   Message=Exception occured when loading
>   configuration from
>   'C:\Users\Mohit\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2010\Projects\Notepad\Notepad\bin\Debug\NLog.config'

It looks like you have a borked configuration file, possibly due to invalid XML or possibly for some more specific reason.

When you get a mysterious XamlParseException, it's *always* worth checking the InnerException for a TargetInvocationException (and drilling in from there if there is one).  Yes, it is very confusing and misleading!

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question but hopefully this will help someone.

I had a property of the main window that was a Business Object... so when the window initialized, the Business Object attempted to initialize... great, but the Data access layer had not been setup, therefore it threw an error...

So c# called that an XML parse error because it happened so early... really it was thrown in code.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the same issue by including the referenced dll and config files in the same folder as the exe file. Trying to run the exe alone will cause a windows level exception.